# Unable to connect

Tags: mysql, windows

I have a Windows Server 2012 machine with ports 3306 open (both incoming and outgoing).  I also have MySQL 5.7 installed, and would like to connect to it remotely.

I have confirmed that `bind-address` is not contained in `my.ini`, and `skip-networking` is commented out.

I have also run the following command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
```

Basically I did everything which all the guides mention, for sending remote connections to the server.  However, when trying to create a connection to the server from my remote machine using the public IP address, I get the 10061 MySQL error saying that a connection could not be established.

In my frustrating efforts, I have also tried connecting with the IP address on the server itself (so from the server to the server), and the same error is received there.  Connecting with localhost works just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: After you made changes to my.ini, have you restarted the server?

Comment: @fancyPants - Yes, always and every time I make a change.

Comment: Not sure why you didn't quote the exact error message but the *using the public IP address* part is kind of vague. Is it really the machine's public address or the router's IP address?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - The IP address you get when googling "what is my ip address"

Comment: And does your Windows machine have a direct connection to the internet? If you can connect other devices or have wifi, the answer is most likely not. You're connecting to a router where MySQL is not running.

Comment: Check your router. Perhaps it has a label with the default address, user and password.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - I do not have access to the router as this is a corporate network. How would you recommend I get the IP address of the PC in that case?

Comment: Then you need to contact your network administrator and ask him to forward a public port to your computer's 3306 port. Only a badly managed network would give total access from outside by default (though, in fact, NAT actually makes that impossible).

Comment: Can you run telnet and connect to port 3306 on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address reported by *what is my ip address* services is the address assigned by your internet provider to your entire subnetwork and it isn't yours; it's shared by all your co-workers. Thus when you connect to such IP address from outside, you aren't connecting to your PC, you're connecting to the internet router. Since that router does not have MySQL installed, you get the *actively refused connection* error.

You need to contact your network administrator and ask him to forward a public port (not necessarily 3306) to your computer's 3306 port.

Using a metaphor, you want mail delivered to your bedroom, but the postman won't do it.